# Integers neither as sum nor difference of perfect powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Are there infinitely many positive integers $n$ for which there do not exist integers $a,b\geq 1$ and $c,d\geq 2$ such that $n=a^c+b^d$ or $n=a^c-b^d$?

[Source: Hungarian competition problem]

Comment: Despite the appearance in the competition, it's widely believed this is an open question. Some discussion in the comments at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/248958/only-finitely-many-natural-numbers-are-not-the-sum-or-difference-of-two-perfect